# Редирект с .php

Tags: .htaccess

Что прописать в .htaccess ?
Для 301 редиректа с .php на без .php

Проштрудировал Google , но попадаются варианты только просто убрать расширение у страниц.

Вот что сейчас в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хостеры сказали что я не могу сделать редирект с .php на конце , на без .php.
Все будет приводить к зацикливанию(